# Formik called `handleChange`, but you forgot to pass an `id` or `name` attribute to your input:undefined

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, formik

I am trying to use Formik with a MaterialUI Select component.

sandbox is here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/lively-wind-75iliv?file=/src/App.tsx

Whenever I select a new value from the drop-down list, the value is not updated and I see on the console the following message:

> Warning: Formik called `handleChange`, but you forgot to pass an `id`
> or `name` attribute to your input:
> undefined
> Formik cannot determine which value to update. For more info see https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#handlechange-e-reactchangeeventany--void

Questions are:

1. how to solve this?
2. am I doing anything not canonical?
3. in general, is it a good idea to use Formik with MaterialUI or should I simply use a native HTML select? (I tried the latter and it is working)

Code is also pasted below:

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useFormik } from 'formik';
import {FormControl, InputLabel, Button, Select, MenuItem} from '@material-ui/core';




export default function App() {


  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      favourite_number: 10
    },
    onSubmit: (values: object) => {
      console.log('about to submit:', values);
      alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
    },
  });

  return (
    <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
    <FormControl fullWidth>
      <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Your favourite number</InputLabel>
      <Select
        labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
        id="demo-simple-select"
        value={formik.values.favourite_number}
        label='Your favourite number'
        onChange={formik.handleChange}
        onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
      >
        <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
      </Select>
    </FormControl>      
    <Button color='primary' variant='contained' fullWidth type='submit'>
      Submit
    </Button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Comment: Try adding `name="favourite_number"` to your select component. The error is fairly straightforward

Comment: @Jamie_D yeah I got sidetracked by the wording "id or name" (I had already supplied an id). stupid..

Answer (score 0):

```
<Select
        labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
        id="demo-simple-select"
        value={formik.values.favourite_number}
        label='Your favourite number'
        name="favourite_number"
        onChange={formik.handleChange}
        onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
      >
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).